# Flextable R: How to keep columns width after adding a header

Tags: r, flextable

I have a tibble with two columns:

```
library('flextable')
library("tidyverse")

df <- tibble('Long' = "Long Long Long Long Long Text", 
             'Short' = 'Short Text')
```

Transform to a flextable:

```
ft <- flextable(data = df,
                theme_fun = theme_zebra)
```

So, I have a table with two equal columns:

[image]

Now I make the left column wider than the left one:

```
ft <- ft %>%
    width(j = 1,
          width = 4) %>%
    width(j = 2,
          width = 1)
```

[image]

And next I add a header:

```
ft <- ft %>%
   add_header_row(values = "Header", colwidths = 2)
```

[image]

As you can see, I now have the flextable with the header and columns of the SAME WIDTH. And no formatting helps anymore. How can I change the width of the columns?

Comment: I am not sure if you are using the latest version, the `theme_fun` argument is deprecated in favor of `set_flextable_defaults` and should not have any effect, to be honnest I don't understand what is happening here! However, with the latest version, this code `flextable(data = df) %>% width(j = 1:2, width = c(4, 1)) %>% add_header_row(values = "Header", colwidths = 2) %>% theme_box()` shoud produce what you are expecting

Comment: @  David Gohel Yeah, you're right. The version was updated and the problem went away. Thanks!